Как проверить JWT токены на Фронтенде Angular?
Подскажите пожалуйста! У меня учебный проект. Есть Frontend на Angular 17 и Backend на  Django Rest Framework.
Пользователь должен иметь возможность авторизоваться через сторонний API (как авторизация через Google).
В моем коде - когда пользователь на Fronend нажимает копку "авторизоваться через API", я перенаправляю его на Backend, затем на
сторонний сервис, он там авторизовывается и на backend приходит ответ от стороннего сервиса что все ОК.
Тогда на Backend я создаю 2 JWT токена и отправляю их в query string GET запросом на Frontend. Frontend ловит этот запрос и
авторизовывает пользователя, но он НЕ ПРОВЕРЯЕТ токены, что они выписаны backend'ом и что они корректные, а только сохраняет их в браузере пользователя.
То есть если я делаю такой же запрос прямо из строки браузера но с фальшивым секретом в токене, то пользователь все равно авторизовывается!
Вопрос - как это исправить? Как проверять токены на то что они действительно не поддельные?
Уточнение:
Я делаю редирект на фронтэнд  frontend_url = f'localhost:4200/auth-success?refresh={refresh}&access={access_token}' return redirect(frontend_url)'
А фронтэнд ловит этот редирект
 { path: 'auth-success', component: OAuthCallbackComponent },
и обрабатывает:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-oauth-callback',
  template: '<p>Intra authentication in process.</p>'
})
export class OAuthCallbackComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const refreshToken = params['refresh'];
      const accessToken = params['access'];     
      localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refreshToken);
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);
      //alert('Authentication successful!');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });
  }
}

но не проверяет токены, а только сохраняет их. Вопрос - как их проверить?

«Тогда на Backend я [...] отправляю их в query string GET запросом на Frontend» — вот эта фраза выглядит как полный бред, Frontend по определению не может принимать никакие запросы. Подозреваю, вы используете терминологию как-то неправильно, из-за чего вопрос в итоге оказывается непонятен

Или, может, вы имеете в виду, что вы выполняете редирект на такой url, из которого Frontend потом может вытащить нужные ему параметры? Впрочем, даже в таком случае это выглядит, во-первых, небезопасно (токен светится открытым текстом в url, какая безответственность), а во-вторых, бессмысленно (Frontend в принципе ничего не должен ничего авторизовывать, авторизацией должен заниматься Backend и никто кроме него)

Пардон, я написал не правильно. Я делаю редирект на фронтэнд frontend_url = f'http://localhost:4200/auth-success?refresh={refresh}&access={access_token}'  return redirect(frontend_url)'

И это нехорошо, потому что все токены светятся открытым текстом в url. Правда, как сделать хорошо с этими вашими новомодными SPA, я как-то не очень знаю

Но в любом случае, независимо от способа передачи токенов — Frontend в принципе ничего не должен авторизовывать, его задача — просто слать токен на Backend в запросах и больше ничего, а уже Backend занимается какими угодно проверками на поддельность

Спасибо, я понял, но как проверить токен на поддельность  на бакэнде?

А это уже должно было быть написано где-то в районе документации той штуки, с помощью которой вы «создали 2 JWT токена»
